# MVC.NET - Multiple action method call from a single view

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm very new to MVC.NET application using kendo ui. I have view which has a kendo drop down list and 2 kendo grids. Drop down will retrieve values(plan/plan ID) from SQL DB using controller and a default value will be assigned to drop down list in controller. Default value of the drop down will be used by Kendo grids(primary and secondary) to retrieve values(resource associated with selected plan) from SQL.

Issue: Controllers associated with kendo grids are not getting selected value of drop down when page is loading. When I logged selected value of drop down in console,  I see blank value is getting logged(see screen attached).  Please let me know what I must do to get the value of the drop down on page load. Thanks

I have provided below drop down, grids and Javascript function details:

```html
<div class="form-group">
                                        @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                            .Name("ddlBenefitPlans")
                            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:360px" })
                            .DataTextField("Text")
                            .DataValueField("Value")
                            .AutoBind(true)
                            .SelectedIndex(1)
                                   
                            .DataSource(source =>
                                    {
                                        source.Read
                                        (read =>
                                              {
                                                  read.Action("GetBenefitPlans", "Home");
                                              }
                                          );
                                        
                                    })
                          .Events(e => e.Change("OnBenefitPlanChange"))
                                        )
                                        
                                    </div>
```

Action method associated with Kendo grid requires three parameters to be passed. Data are passed using javascript function.

```html
<div>
                    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Beneficiary.Areas.p.Models.IndividualList>()
                    .Name("primaryGrid")
                    .Scrollable(sc => sc.Height(140))
                    .Pageable()
                    .Scrollable()
                    .AutoBind(true)
                    .Events(x => x.DataBound("primaryGridDataBound"))
                    .Columns(column =>
                    {
                        column.Template(@<text><a class="btn btn-link btn-xs"></a></text>).
                        ClientTemplate("<a onclick=ShowModalDialog('#=PlanLinkID#')>Delete</a>").Title("Action");
                        column.Bound(p => p.FirstName).Title("Name");
                        //column.Bound(p => p.Distribute).Title("Percentage %");//.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "font-weight:bold;" }).Hidden( p => p.DistributeEven = 0);
                        column.Bound(p => p.Percentage)
                        .ClientTemplate("<input class='numeric' type='number' value='#= Percentage #' min='0' max='100' step='1' id='PrimaryPercentage_#=PlanLinkID#' name='PrimaryPercentage_#=PlanLinkID#'/><input id='PrimaryPercentageDispute_#=PlanLinkID#' name='PrimaryPercentageDispute_#=PlanLinkID#' visible='false' ReadOnly='true'/>");
                        column.Bound(p => p.Address).Title("Address");
                        column.Bound(p => p.RelationShip).Title("Relationship");
                        column.Bound(p => p.IndividualID).Visible(false);
                        column.Bound(p => p.DistributeEven).Visible(false);

                    })
                    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                    .Ajax()
                    .Read(read => read.Action("IndividualList", "Home").Data("GetBenefitPlanAndPrimary"))
                    )

                    )
                    
                </div>
```

```html
<div>
                    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Beneficiary.Areas.p.Models.IndividualList>()
            .Name("secondaryGrid")
    .Scrollable(sc => sc.Height(140))
    .Pageable()
    .Scrollable()
    .AutoBind(true)
            .Events(x => x.DataBound("secondaryGridDataBound"))
    .Columns(column =>
                   {
                       column.Template(@<text><a class="btn btn-link btn-xs"></a></text>).
                       ClientTemplate("<a onclick=ShowModalDialog('#=PlanLinkID#')>Delete</a>").Title("Action");
                       column.Bound(p => p.FirstName).Title("Name");
                       //column.Bound(p => p.Distribute).Title("Percentage %").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "font-weight:bold;" }).Hidden(Model.DistributeEven != 0);
                       column.Bound(p => p.Percentage)
                       .ClientTemplate("<input class='numeric' type='number' value='#= Percentage #' min='0' max='100' step='1' id='SecondaryPercentage_#=PlanLinkID#' name='SecondaryPercentage_#=PlanLinkID#'/><input id='SecondaryPercentageDispute_#=PlanLinkID#' name='SecondaryPercentageDispute_#=PlanLinkID#' value='Dispute' visible='false' ReadOnly='true'/>");
                       column.Bound(p => p.Address).Title("Address");
                                           column.Bound(p => p.RelationShip).Title("Relationship");
                       column.Bound(p => p.IndividualID).Visible(false);
                       column.Bound(p => p.DistributeEven).Visible(false);
                   })
                                             .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                             .Ajax()
                                                     .Read(read => read.Action("IndividualList", "Home").Data("GetBenefitPlanAndSecondary"))
                                          )
                    )

                </div>
```

```js
function GetBenefitPlanAndPrimary() {
        console.log($("#ddlBenefitPlans").data("kendoDropDownList").value());
        return {
            benefitPlanID: $("#ddlBenefitPlans").data("kendoDropDownList").value(),
            isPrimOrSecondary: 1,
            Masked: true,
        };
    }
    function GetBenefitPlanAndSecondary() {
        console.log($("#ddlBenefitPlans").data("kendoDropDownList").value());
        return {
            benefitPlanID: $("#ddlBenefitPlans").data("kendoDropDownList").value(),
            isPrimOrSecondary: 3,
            Masked: true,
        };
    }
```

Action method associated with drop down:

```js
public JsonResult GetBenefitPlans([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            List<BenefitPlans> lBenefitPlans = beneficiaryBL.GetBenefitPlans();
            List<SelectListItem> lstBenefitPlans = new List<SelectListItem>();
            SelectListItem item = new SelectListItem();
            item.Text = "Select"; item.Value = string.Empty;
            lstBenefitPlans.Add(item);
            Boolean isItemSelected = false;
            foreach (BenefitPlans p in lBenefitPlans)
            {
                item = new SelectListItem() { Text = p.BenefitPlan, Value = p.ID.ToString() };
                if (!isItemSelected)
                {
                    item.Selected = true;
                    isItemSelected = true;
                }
                lstBenefitPlans.Add(item);
            }
            lstBenefitPlans[1].Selected = true;
            JsonResult result = Json(lstBenefitPlans, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            return result;
        }
```

Action method associated with Kendo list:

```js
public ActionResult IndividualList(Int16 benefitPlanID, Int16 isPrimOrSecondary, [DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, bool Masked = false)
        {
            List<IndividualList> lIndList = new List<IndividualList>();
            IndividualList ind = null;
            decimal totalPercentage = 0;
            DataSourceResult dataSourceResult = new DataSourceResult();
            List<Entities.AssignedBeneficiariesByBeneficiary> l = null;
                        l = beneficiaryBL.GetAssignedBeneficiariesByBeneficiaryFormID(BeneficiaryFormID, benefitPlanID, isPrimOrSecondary);
            if (l != null && l.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (Entities.AssignedBeneficiariesByBeneficiary indv in l)
                {
                    ind = new IndividualList();
                    ind.PlanLinkID = indv.PlanLinkID;
                    ind.IndividualID = indv.BeneficiaryID;
                    ind.FirstName = string.Concat(indv.FirstName, " ", indv.LastName);
                    ind.LastName = indv.LastName;
                    ind.Name = indv.FirstName + " " + indv.LastName;                  
                    lIndList.Add(ind);

                }
            }
            dataSourceResult = lIndList.ToList().ToDataSourceResult(request);
            JsonResult result = Json(dataSourceResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            return result;
        }
```

[Network traffic screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPwLZ.jpg)

[Controller Method 1 is not receiving value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiBb2.jpg)

[Controller Method 2 is not receiving value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zmjw8.jpg)

Comment: Is it possible that your `GetBenefitPlanAndPrimary` function is getting called by your grid before `#ddlBenefitPlans` is databound?

Comment: Try setting `.AutoBind(false)` on your grids, then create a `.DataBound` event for your DropDown list that triggers the grids to bind once its databound. If the grid relies on data from another widget, you probably have to wait until that widget is databound.

Comment: I followed the steps you recommended and I was able to resolve the issue. Thank you.  Additionally I referred to telerik link - https://www.telerik.com/forums/loading-grid-on-dropdownlist-change-or-button-click-event where same question was asked.